# How to apply a shining to DAE model in SceneKit?

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

What I am trying to do is add shininess to a `.dae` model in SceneKit.

[image]

How can I add shininess to this model?

Answer (score 1):

At first select your `.dae` model and choose <kbd>Editor</kbd> – <kbd>Convert to SceneKit File Format (.scn)</kbd> in main menu.

After that get through the hierarchy with `.childNodes[0]` to retrieve the model. Then apply a `.blinn` shader and setup `specular.intensity` and `shininess` parameters.

```
import SceneKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let sceneView = self.view as! SCNView
        sceneView.scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!
        sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
        sceneView.backgroundColor = .black
        sceneView.scene?.lightingEnvironment.contents = .none
        sceneView.scene?.background.contents = .none

        let sun = SCNNode()
        sun.light = SCNLight()
        sun.light?.type = .directional
        sun.light?.intensity = 500
        sun.eulerAngles.x = -.pi/2
        sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(sun)

        let s = sceneView.scene!.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ship", 
                                                 recursively: true)!

        s.childNodes[0].geometry?.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = .blinn
        s.childNodes[0].geometry?.firstMaterial?.shininess = 100
        s.childNodes[0].geometry?.firstMaterial?.specular.intensity = 100
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I thought the shininess option was ignored on PBR materials in scenekit :-)

Comment: @ZAY, you are the source of truth, you're absolutely right  :)